# How to configure the shutdown port in IntelliJ 14 built-in Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, configuration, remote-server

Running IntelliJ 14, with Tomcat 8.  I'm currently doing most of my development work with the built-in server catalina_base generated from my Tomcat 8 server, but now I want to work on deploying to the main Tomcat 8 installation.  Why?  Mostly to try to understand what is going on, so that I have an idea of what I can and cannot do before trying seriously to attempt different ways of doing the deployment (it's a Maven project, so I've got all of those flavors to figure out, too).

It seems to be the case, based on my online readings and my experience, that even if I configure a Tomcat run configuration based on a Tomcat Local template, unless I set that as the default (which I haven't tried), IntelliJ will use the built-in server.  But I have the impression that once I've set a local server default configuration, that's it: bye-bye to IntelliJ's built-in server, and I'm not ready to get rid of that yet.

So, I decided to try configuring my Tomcat 8 server as a Tomcat Remote configuration, which means the whole staging directory thing, and it requires that the local server (in my case, the built-in server) also be running.  I've got it to transfer the file OK (.war file), but I've been running into port conflicts as the target server tries to start up.

No biggie to reconfigure the HTTP and AJP ports on the built-in server, there are fields for that in the Run Configuration dialog.  But how do I reconfigure the shutdown port for the built-in server?  Can I just edit server.xml in the catalina_base/conf/server.xml?  I can see that conf, logs, and work were generated from their corresponding folders in tomcat_home, but do they get re-created with each build or configuration change, or is it a one-time thing, and then all further edits are independent of my main Tomcat installation?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just edit server.xml in the catalina_base/conf/server.xml?

You should edit the original Tomcat configuration, not the copy under IntelliJ IDEA [idea.system.path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory.

For example, `d:\dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\conf\server.xml`, edit `<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`

Comment: That wouldn't resolve the port conflict that I'm having, would it?  Wait, maybe it would.  I'll try that.    It may still just be that pretending the local server is a remote server won't accomplish what I had hoped.  But yeah, I tried editing the shutdown port in the idea.system.path, and it got me a startup error about port 1099 (JMX) already being in use, though as far as I'm aware I don't have any other servers running.  Also, it changed the shutdown port on its own to 50273.  :-(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the built-in server. IntelliJ IDEA has no built-in Tomcat. It either runs Tomcat you've configured or it connects to Tomcat you already have running via the Remote configuration.

Comment: I've seen it referred to as the "built-in" server.  It's based off the Tomcat server that I installed separately and pointed IntelliJ to, but instead of using catalina_base = catalina_home, there is a catalina_base that IntelliJ creates.  On my machine, it's at C:\Users\myUserName\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_myProjectName_2.  It's confusing.  Anyway, I did try changing the shutdown port in tomcat_home\conf\server.xml, and so now there are no more conflicts, and the application is deployed, but the browser isn't launched automatically and no log files are displayed.

Comment: If the server is started and IntelliJ IDEA detects the app deployment from the log, it will open the browser automatically. You may want to try a more recent IntelliJ IDEA version.